# How to take snapshot when every document is added/ deleted/ updated in index in elastic search cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a s3 bucket and repository is registered.

We want to take snapshot whenever documents are added/deleted/updated in index in elastic search cluster.

Do we have any option to do this in elastic search or any other way to do this. Pls suggest ?

Comment: Elasticsearch has a Snapshot management that allows you to create scheduled policies to run snapshots, but it will run on a fixed time, not on every document change. The documentation can be [found here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/snapshots-take-snapshot.html#automate-snapshots-slm).

Comment: You can use an external queue or directly run a snapshot with the same code your application uses to manage docs in ES. If docs are changed directly in the ES, it's possible to write a watcher which would retrieve `total` and `deleted` doc counts for an index and fire away a snapshot when it changes. Too many snapshots can cause "denial of service" though.

Answer (score 0):

tldr there's nothing native to Elasticsearch that will take a snapshot "whenever documents are added/deleted/updated". if you had a high rate of change in your docs, that'd be unrealistic anyway

you can create snapshots on a schedule using SLM - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.0/snapshots-take-snapshot.html#automate-snapshots-slm, which would be the next best thing